# Why is my Tk button being pressed automatically?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In the code below, clicking the button should change the black text from Hello to Goodbye.  But when I run the program, it immediately says Goodbye.

[image]

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
print "this is a test"


class Demo(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.createGUI()
        print "init"
        #self.__mainWindow = Tk()
    def destroy(self):
        print "destroy"
    def createGUI(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
        self.master.title("Demo")
        self.trackLabel = StringVar()
        self.trackLabel.set("Hello")
        self.trackDisplay = Label(self, font = "Courier 14", textvariable = self.trackLabel, bg = "black", fg = "green")
        self.trackDisplay.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)
        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Click Me", width = 10, command = self.bpress())
        self.button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    def bpress(self):
        self.trackLabel.set("Goodbye")
# run the program
def main():
    tts = Demo()
    tts.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are calling `self.bpress` when you create the `self.button1` button:

```
self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Click Me", width = 10, command = self.bpress())
#                                                                               ^^
```

Simply remove the parenthesis and assign `command` to the `self.bpress` function object itself:

```
self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Click Me", width = 10, command = self.bpress)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will accept your answer when the website lets me!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

If you want to send parameters to the function, simply add `lambda:`

Example for a button with the command `callback()`:

```
yourButton = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Go!", command= lambda: callback(variableOne, variableTwo, variableThree)).pack()
```